# How the browser identifies the CSS framework?

Tags: html, css, browser

I am new to web development. So in addition to writing HTML, CSS and JS, I am also exploring about how they are actually rendered by the browser. I researched about JS engines like V8 and layout engines like Gecko etc.

Now I get a doubt. The purpose of layout engine is to process the HTML/CSS and display them properly to the user. However, there are a lot of CSS frameworks out there, like Bootstrap and Pure. So if some element, say button, is common to both frameworks, how does the browser know how to display the button according to the framework?

Has this got something to do with the bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js etc which we include in the HEAD section? If these are like libraries which are used to parse the CSS and display the elements to the users, then is the layout engine just a funnel which takes in the library and source code and produce the output?

Comment: You have a lot of learnin' to do. It doesn't have to do with the "framework" (the browser is never aware of this). Read up on [cascading, precedence and specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

Comment: The CSS is processed in the order the rules are created in the document. Specificity then dictates the final rendering. JavaScript can also influence the display, however while the order matters, various timing (setInterval, setTimeout) and asynchronous functions (i.e. AJAX) can influence the rendering as well.

Comment: In your research you have missed CSS basics. For example: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add style to your HTML code, or attach an external stylesheet using `<link>` in the `<head>` segment of your markup, the browser loads that resource for you. CSS files contain styling property definitions for different HTML elements (like `a, li, table` etc.), classes (like `btn-default` or `table-striped`), and IDs (like `myDivID` or  `mainTable`).

So, in answering your question, files like `bootstrap.min.css`, when included in your HTML markup, provide CSS styling rules to be applied to the elements on your page. In this particular case `bootstrap.min.js` provides JavaScript functionality to some of the elements included in Bootstrap, such as dropdowns, scrollspys, etc (see [Bootstrap JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)). Your browser has no concept of what CSS framework it is using, it simply loads styling rules from CSS files in the order that you provide them.

When a page is loaded by a user, these styling properties are inserted by the browser into the corresponding DOM elements. If an element is common to two or more different stylesheets or styling definitions that have overlapping style rules, the one loaded last is given priority, unless a particular styling value is given the `!important` CSS rule (in which case styling rules marked `!important` take priority).

Comment: Note: For inline code, you only need one backtick on either side, not three?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've updated my answer to reflect your advice.